# Calculate Mutual Information between the frequency components of two 2-D images (Python)

Tags: python, image, numpy, information-theory

I'm hoping to calculate the mutual information in bits between two images. Specifically, I would like to calculate the mutual info as a function of the two images' frequency components. (e.g. lots of mutual info between the images in low frequency but not as much in high frequency). Is there a way to do so in Python?

I can use `np.fft` functions to find the frequency components of any image and the `mutual_information_2d` function [this link](https://gist.github.com/GaelVaroquaux/ead9898bd3c973c40429) to calculate the 2D mutual info between two images. But, how can I piece this all together? Is it a simple matter of calculating the mutual info (using the latter function) on the frequency components obtained from the former functions separately at each frequency? Or is there more to this?

Comment: May I ask you why are using applying `np.fft` over the image?

Comment: To be precise, I am using `np.fft.fft2`, `np.fft.fftshift`, `np.fft.ifftshift`, and `np.fft.ifft2` in that order to obtain the frequency decomposition of the image